# DNS - DKIM TXT result in error?

Tags: dns, cpanel, dkim

I have been experiencing some trouble when using cPanel and DKIM keys at my DNS provider.

The problem (From their opinion) was that my DKIM key inside the TXT file made all other DNS records stop working when the DKIM key expired (after 7 days)

My question is:

Is this true-> Will an expired TXT DKIM record make my A, Cname and MX records stop working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That makes absolutely no sense at all. The content in a `TXT` record cannot possibly affect any other resource record. At least not in DNS, I cannot say anything about whatever strangeness the provider may have implemented in their own system.